# On WordPress Archives Display All Posts

Tags: wordpress

I need to be able to display all posts on WordPress archive pages, but I do not know how to make that happen. I have tried using the following code, but it does not work.

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'all_posts');
function all_posts( $query ) {
if ($query->is_category()){
$query->set( 'posts_per_page' => -1, true );
}}
```

I tried changing it into this:

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'all_posts');
function all_posts( $query ) {
if ($query->is_category()){
$query->set( '-1' , true );
}}
```

Comment: All posts for the relevant archive (category), or literally all posts regardless of category?

Comment: All posts regardless of category, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'all_posts');
function all_posts( $query ) {
    if ($query->is_category()){
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page' , -1 );
        $query->set( 'post_type', 'post' );
    }
}
```

Comment: I did this, which worked.
add_action('pre_get_posts', function($query){
if (is_category()){$query->set('posts_per_page', -1);
}});